# rich calendar date formatting

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I use rich:calendar with a specific pattern `datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"`. When I tried to get the string value from the calendar and parse it using `SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy")` I had some issues and I saw the date format in my variable is not what I expected: `Tue Nov 22 00:00:00 EET 2011`

Here is some code:

> rich:calendar

```
<rich:calendar value="#{validateReportAction.selectedDate}"  
   required="true" 
   requiredMessage="You must select a date" 
   mode="ajax"
   id="date"
   datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
```

> in bean

```
DateFormat formatter;
Date date; 
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
date = (Date) formatter.parse(getSelectedDate());
```

where `getSelectedDate()` returns `Tue Nov 22 00:00:00 EET 2011` but I want only the day/month/year. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @reporter what did you change?

Comment: I added the tags 'java' and 'jsf'.

Comment: Maistora, please don't get confused with `Date#toString()`: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29 A `System.out.println(new Date())` will output exactly this kind of value. Don't focus too much on it. What do you really want and expect? What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: BalusC, I just want to have date formatted like so "dd/MM/yyyy" that I can easily insert into my postgres DB. And I store the date from the calendar to a String var. I thought that it should be formatted like I said (datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy") and when I print it it shouldn't call the Date toString because it is just a String. I want to have 22/11/2011 in my String var.

Comment: You should use `Date` in Java side and `DATE` in SQL side, not `String` and `VARCHAR` or something. Use the right type for the data it holds. Otherwise you would be unable to properly sort the column by date or to select some rows which is between two dates, for example. That `datePattern` is just to format the `Date` object in the UI to humans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code that i have that works properly;

```
<rich:calendar id="scheduledDateStart" 
            value="#{Scheduled.scheduledDateStart}"
    popup="true" 
            enableManualInput="#{true}"
            scrollMode="client"                             
           timeZone="#{timeZone.timeZone}"
   datePattern="MM,dd,yyyy"                             
 >                   
 <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="MMMM dd, yyyy"  timeZone="#{timeZone.timeZone}"/>
</rich:calendar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this attribute inside your  tag and see if it fixes the issue:

```
<f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"  timeZone="#{timeZone.timeZone}"/>
```

Regards!

Comment: What is the type of selectedDate in your backing bean?

Comment: Change it to Date type. Date selectedDate. Then make sure you have the proper getter and setter methods for the DATE object.

Comment: This worked neither. This is the output:
date: 'Wed Nov 23 00:00:00 EET 2011' could not be understood as a date.

Comment: Posted my code as an answer. Check it out. Also my date is a Date object.

Comment: The thing with the DATE worked I don't know what happened last time. Thanks!